# Taking a specific action on reaching a number

Tags: javascript, css, return, dom-events

I'm learning JavaScript, and decided to try out a simple guessing game thing. The code I have at the moment:

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Guessing Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
     
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="guessing_game.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the guessing game</h1>
<p>You have to guess the number within 5 attempts, so good luck!</p>

<p>Enter a number:</p>
<input type="text" id="number" placeholder="Enter number"></br>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Guess!"></br>
<aside>
    <div id="counter">

    <p>Remaining Guesses</p>
    </div>
    <p id="remaining"></p>  
</aside>
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="guessing_game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
var guesses = 5;

function guess() {
    var elGuess = document.getElementById("remaining");
    var elResult = document.getElementById("result");
/*  if(guesses === 0) {
        elResult.innerHTML = "<p>Sorry, you ran out of guesses! Better 
        luck next time.</p>";
        return;
    }*/

    if(guesses > 0) {

        guesses--;
        elGuess.textContent = guesses;

        //random number
        var secret = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

        var elUserGuess = document.getElementById("number");
        var userGuess = parseInt(elUserGuess.value);

        

        if(userGuess == secret) {
            elResult.textContent = "Congrats! You did it";
        }

        else {
            elResult.textContent = "Sorry, please try again.";
        }
    }

    else {
        elResult.textContent = "Sorry, you ran out of guesses.";
    }            
    
}

var elSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");
elSubmit.addEventListener("click", guess, false);
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

aside {
    position: relative;
    top: -150px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    float: right;
    border-left: 2px solid gray;
}

#counter p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    width: 140px;
    left: 60px;
    border-top: 2px solid brown;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid brown;
    padding: 5px;
}

#remaining {
    font-size: 220%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, serif;
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    padding: 2px;
    left: 130px;
    color: #ff2400;

}

#result {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.9em;
    color: gray;

}
```

What I was looking to do was - as soon as the number of guesses reach 0, the result should display that you're out of guesses. I've managed to validate the guesses counting down to 0 (not going to negative). I tried using an if statement which would check if the guesses were out, then set the result accordingly and `return`. But apparently, as soon as `return` is reached, the control exits the method. I didn't know this would happen even inside an if that's never reached.

Either way, how do I modify the code such that the result is set as soon as the guesses left hit zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that your variable guesses might not be what is displaying on the remaining element, you should decrement the variable before your condition.

```
var guesses = 5;

function guess() {
    var elGuess = document.getElementById("remaining");
    var elResult = document.getElementById("result");

    if (guesses===0){
        return;
    }

    guesses--;

    elGuess.textContent = guesses;

    if(guesses > 0) {

        var secret = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

        var elUserGuess = document.getElementById("number");
        var userGuess = parseInt(elUserGuess.value);



        if(userGuess == secret) {
            elResult.textContent = "Congrats! You did it";
        }

        else {
            elResult.textContent = "Sorry, please try again.";
        }
    }
    else {
        elResult.textContent = "Sorry, you ran out of guesses.";
    }            

}

var elSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");
elSubmit.addEventListener("click", guess, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about decrementing the `guesses` variable in the right place. I haven't been able to run this code yet, but wouldn't the `return` in the if block end the method at the very beginning itself? Something similar to what I was going for...

Comment: The return statment will only trigger when you already reach 0 guesses, and this will prevent your guesses going below 0. This will not trigger if you have 1 guess left and you click on the button. Just check this putting a `console.log(guesses);` one line before your commented statment to see how your variable interacts with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're decrementing your guesses counter inside that if statement, you need to move your check for `guesses === 0` inside of that same block somewhere below `guesses--;`

```
if (guesses > 0) {

    guesses--;
    elGuess.textContent = guesses;

    //random number
    var secret = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    var elUserGuess = document.getElementById("number");
    var userGuess = parseInt(elUserGuess.value);

    if (userGuess == secret) {
        elResult.textContent = "Congrats! You did it";
    }

    if (guesses === 0) {
      elResult.textContent = "Sorry, you ran out of guesses."
    } else {
      elResult.textContent = "Sorry, please try again.";
    }
}
```

Also, next time you post a question like this consider also linking to a free online sandbox like CodePen or JSBin. That way people can edit your code without having to copy/paste.

Here's the CodePen I made for your question:
http://codepen.io/ultralame/pen/OyWbeW.js

Comment: Thanks for the CodePen info! While I've seen people use it before for answers, I didn't quite get it's importance then. All clear now.